# Segmentation Fault- Polynomial

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, segmentation-fault, fault

I have made a basic program in order to manipulate polynomial, using `std::map.

Here's the source code

polynome.hpp

```
#ifndef POLYNOME_HPP
#define POLYNOME_HPP

using namespace std;


template<typename T> 
string to_string( const T & Value ) 
{ 
//Utiliser un flux de sortie pour créer la chaîne 
ostringstream oss; 
//Ecrire la valeur dans le flux
oss << Value; 
//Renvoyer une string 
return oss.str(); 
} 

template <typename T>
class Polynome
{
public:
    //Constructeurs et destructeur
    Polynome();
    Polynome(const Polynome &);
    Polynome(T (tab[]), unsigned int);
    Polynome(map<unsigned int, T>&);
    ~Polynome(){}
    //Méthodes d'accès
    unsigned int GetOrder() const {return ItsOrder;}
    map<unsigned int, T> GetPoly() const {return ItsPolynome;}
    void SetOrder(unsigned int order) { ItsOrder=order;}
    void SetPoly(map<unsigned int, T> poly){ItsPolynome=poly;}
    //Surcharge d'opérateur
    T & operator[](unsigned int);
    T operator[](unsigned int) const;
    Polynome operator+(const Polynome &);
    Polynome operator-(const Polynome &);
    Polynome operator*(const Polynome &);
    Polynome& operator=(const Polynome &);
    template <typename U>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Polynome<U>&);
    //Autres méthodes
    void Deriv();
    T Eval(const Polynome &, T);

private:
    //Données membres
    map<unsigned int,T> ItsPolynome;
    unsigned int ItsOrder;
 };

 //Constructeur par défaut
 template <typename T>
 Polynome<T>::Polynome(): ItsOrder(0)
 {
 map<unsigned int, T> m;
 m[0]=0;
 ItsPolynome=m;;
 }

 //Constructeur de copie
 template <typename T>
 Polynome<T>::Polynome(const Polynome<T> & rhs)
 {
   map<unsigned int, T> m;
   m[0]=0;
   ItsPolynome=m;
   map<unsigned int, T> a=rhs.GetPoly();
   for(typename map<unsigned int, T>::const_iterator ii=a.begin();ii!=a.end(); ++ii)
{
    ItsPolynome[ii->first] = ii->second;
}

ItsOrder=rhs.GetOrder();
}

//Constructeur à partir d'un tableau contenant les coefficients
template <typename T>
Polynome<T>::Polynome(T (tab)[],unsigned int size)
{
map<unsigned int, T> m;
m[0]=0;
ItsOrder=0;
ItsPolynome=m;
for(unsigned int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    ItsPolynome[i]=tab[i];
}
ItsOrder=size-1;
}

//Constructeur qui prend une map(tableau associatif) en paramètre
template <typename T>
Polynome<T>::Polynome(map<unsigned int, T> & a)
{
ItsPolynome=a;
unsigned int b=0;
for(typename map<unsigned int, T>::const_iterator ii=a.begin();ii!=a.end(); ++ii)
{
    if((ii->first)>b)
    {
        b=ii->first;
    }
}
ItsOrder=b;
}

//Opérateur d'indexation  non constant
template <typename T>
T & Polynome<T>::operator[](unsigned int n)
{
if(ItsPolynome.count(n))
{
    return ItsPolynome[n];
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
}

//Opérateur d'indexation constant
template <typename T>
T Polynome<T>::operator[](unsigned int n) const
{
if(ItsPolynome.count(n))
{
    return ItsPolynome[n];
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
}

//Surcharge de l'opérateur +
template <typename T>
Polynome<T> Polynome<T>::operator+(const Polynome<T> & rhs)
{
map<unsigned int, T> polyrhs=rhs.GetPoly();
/*On définit l'ordre du nouveau polynôme obtenu. */
if(ItsOrder<rhs.GetOrder())
{
    ItsOrder=rhs.GetOrder();
}
/* On additionne enfin les deux polynômes pour obtenir une map pour le polynôme obtenu suite à l'addition. */
for(typename map<unsigned int, T>::const_iterator ii=polyrhs.begin();ii!=polyrhs.end(); ++ii)
{
    ItsPolynome[ii->first]+=polyrhs[ii->first];
}
}

//Surcharge de l'opérateur - (analogue à la surcharge de l'opérateur +)
template <typename T>
Polynome<T> Polynome<T>::operator-(const Polynome<T> & rhs)
{
map<unsigned int, T> polyrhs=rhs.GetPoly();
/*On définit l'ordre du nouveau polynôme obtenu. */
if(ItsOrder<rhs.GetOrder())
{
    ItsOrder=rhs.GetOrder();
}
/* On additionne enfin les deux polynômes pour obtenir une map pour le polynôme obtenu suite à l'addition. */
for(typename map<unsigned int, T>::const_iterator ii=polyrhs.begin();ii!=polyrhs.end(); ++ii)
{
    ItsPolynome[ii->first]-=polyrhs[ii->first];
}
}

//Surcharge de l'opérateur *
template <typename T>
Polynome<T> Polynome<T>::operator*(const Polynome<T> & rhs)
{
map<unsigned int, T> polyrhs=rhs.GetPoly();
/*On définit l'ordre du nouveau polynôme obtenu. */
ItsOrder=ItsOrder+rhs.GetOrder();
/* On additionne enfin les deux polynômes pour obtenir une map pour le polynôme obtenu suite à l'addition. */
for(int i=0;i<=ItsOrder;i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<=i;j++)
    {
        ItsPolynome[i]+=ItsPolynome[j]*polyrhs[i-j];
    }
    }
    }

    //Surcharge de l'opérateur de flux
    template <typename T>
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, Polynome<T>& p)
   {
    string a="", b="", c="";
    map<unsigned int, T> poly=p.GetPoly();
    for(typename map<unsigned int, T>::const_iterator ii=poly.begin();ii!=poly.end(); ++ii)
    {
    b=to_string(ii->second);
    c=to_string(ii->first);
    a+="+"+b+"x^"+c;
        }
    stream<<a;

    return stream;
    }

    //Surcharge de l'opérateur d'affectation
    template <typename T>
    Polynome<T>& Polynome<T>::operator=(const Polynome<T> & rhs)
    {
if(this==&rhs)
{
    return *this;
}
ItsOrder=rhs.GetOrder();
ItsPolynome=rhs.GetPoly();
return *this;
}

//Méthode permettant de dériver le polynôme
template <typename T>
void Polynome<T>::Deriv()
{
//On définit l'ordre du polynôme dérivé
if(ItsOrder==0)
{
    ItsOrder=0;
}
else
{
    ItsOrder--;
}
//On définit les coefficients du polynôme dérivé (On prend chaque a*x^n un a un, et la dérivation le transforme en a*n*x^(n-1) )
for(typename map<unsigned int, T>::const_iterator ii=ItsPolynome.begin();ii!=ItsPolynome.end(); ++ii)
{
    if((ii->first)!=0)
    {
        ItsPolynome[ii->first-1]=(ii->second)*(ii->first);
        ItsPolynome[ii->first]=0;
    }
  }
  }

  //Méthode permettant d'évaluer le polynôme en un point x
  template <typename T>
  T Polynome<T>::Eval(const Polynome<T> & p, T x)
  {
T a=0;
map<unsigned int, T> poly=p.GetPoly();
for(typename map<unsigned int, T>::const_iterator ii=poly.begin();ii!=poly.end(); ++ii)
{
    a+=(ii->second)*(pow(x,ii->first));
}
return a;
 }

 #endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream> 
#include <cmath>
#include <map>
#include "polynome.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
double tab[3]={1.0,1.0,1.0};
map<unsigned int, double> m;
m[0]=1;
m[1]=1;
m[2]=1;
Polynome<double> p(m);
Polynome<double> q(tab,3);
Polynome<double> r;

cout<<p<<endl;
cout<<q<<endl;

r=p+q;

cout<<r<<endl;

return 0;
 }

 /*Le programme a été écrit sur gedit, et compilé sous gcc avec le warning  Weffc++ */
```

This program compile, but there is the followings warnings

```
In file included from main.cpp:7:0:
polynome.hpp: In instantiation of ‘Polynome<T>::Polynome(std::map<unsigned int, T>&) [with T = double]’:
main.cpp:18:22:   required from here
polynome.hpp:94:1: warning: ‘Polynome<double>::ItsPolynome’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
 Polynome<T>::Polynome(map<unsigned int, T> & a)
 ^
polynome.hpp:94:1: warning: ‘Polynome<double>::ItsOrder’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
polynome.hpp: In instantiation of ‘Polynome<T>::Polynome(T*, unsigned int) [with T = double]’:
main.cpp:19:26:   required from here
polynome.hpp:79:1: warning: ‘Polynome<double>::ItsPolynome’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
 Polynome<T>::Polynome(T (tab)[],unsigned int size)
 ^
polynome.hpp:79:1: warning: ‘Polynome<double>::ItsOrder’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
polynome.hpp: In instantiation of ‘Polynome<T>::Polynome() [with T = double]’:
main.cpp:20:19:   required from here
polynome.hpp:54:1: warning: ‘Polynome<double>::ItsPolynome’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
 Polynome<T>::Polynome(): ItsOrder(0)
 ^
```

and the result of this is:

"+1x^0+1x^1+1x^2

+1x^0+1x^1+1x^2

Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
"

So, i want to understand, what is wrong in my program, in the methods of addition, because i think that the problem is here.

Thank you very much to read this. ;)

PS: Sorry for my english, i am french.
and sorry for the presentation of the code.
If you want, I traduce the comments, i can do this if you want. ;)

:-)

Comment: You can get rid of your `Polynome` copy constructor and `operator=`.   There is no need for it, as all of your types are safely copyable using the compiler default copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. :-) I can delete these methods ? Sure ?

Comment: Yes, those functions should be deleted.  Your class as it's coded now does not require those functions.  By including them, you're increasing the chance that bugs can occur.  As to your error, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious errors that I see immediately is that you do not return values from functions that require a return value.

For example, look at your `operator+` function:

```
template <typename T>
Polynome<T> Polynome<T>::operator+(const Polynome<T> & rhs)
{
    map<unsigned int, T> polyrhs = rhs.GetPoly();
    if (ItsOrder<rhs.GetOrder())
    {
        ItsOrder = rhs.GetOrder();
    }
    for (typename map<unsigned int, T>::const_iterator ii = polyrhs.begin(); ii != polyrhs.end(); ++ii)
    {
        ItsPolynome[ii->first] += polyrhs[ii->first];
    }
  // <-- Where is the return value?
}
```

You do not return a value.  Not returning a value is *undefined behavior*.  The function is supposed to return a `Polymer<T>` object, but you did not do so.

You make the same mistake with your other overloaded operators, so you need to change those also. And certain operators, such as `+`, should be `const` to the object they're executed against You need to return a *crafted* object by value; not modify the existing object:

```
//Surcharge de l'opérateur +
template <typename T>
Polynome<T> Polynome<T>::operator+(const Polynome<T> & rhs) const
{
    Polynome<T> res = *this; // make copy of this object

    res.ItsOrder = std::max(res.ItsOrder, rhs.ItsOrder);
    for(auto const& term : rhs.ItsPolynome)
        res.ItsPolynome[term.first] += term.second;
    return res; // return crafted object by-value.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value for `operator+()`.  The same applies for `operator-()`and `operator*()`.

**What's wrong ?**

You have defined all these operators to overwrite the current object, so `p+q` would modify `p` instead of leaving `p` and `q` untouched and producing a result.  As you don't return a value, it's completely undefined what the assignment operator may copy.  Hence the segfault.

**What's also wrong ?**

If you'd return `*this`, the code would compile but will not work as you expect !  For the simple expression `r=p+q`, it would overwrite `p` with the content of `p+q` and would copy the new value of `p` to `r`. `r` is as you expect, but did you want `p` to change ?  Your code won't work at all for more complex operations.  Suppose you'd write an expression like `r = (p+q)*(p-q)`;  Your code would produce undefined behaviour, depending on the order in which your compiler would evaluate the expression !

**Suggestion for solving the issue**

Have a look at **[this guideline article](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html)** about operator implementation.

In the meantime, here an adapted version that works:

```
template <typename T>
Polynome<T> Polynome<T>::operator+(const Polynome<T> & rhs)
{
    Polynome<T> t=*this ; // temporary polynom to return 
    if (t.ItsOrder<rhs.GetOrder())  
        t.ItsOrder = rhs.GetOrder();  // take the max
    for (auto ii = rhs.ItsPolynome.begin(); ii != rhs.ItsPolynome.end(); ++ii)
        t.ItsPolynome[ii->first] += ii->second;
    return t ;
}
```

Comment: Deriv works, I tested it.

But for the others, I think you're right, I will correct it.

Comment: Yes indeed, Deriv works.  I just wanted to draw your attention that it overvrites the polynôme that is being derived.  I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your operator+ function - you say it returns `Polynome<T>` but there is no return statement.

Add: `return *this` after the for loop and it should work.

Comment: I don't know if `return *this*` really works for operator +.  A brand new object should be returned, not the current object.  If the code were moved to an `operator +=`, then yes, a `return *this*` would be justified.

Comment: But the code is not creating a brand new object - it is updating one of the operands.

Comment: Clearly there is a problem with what the code does and the name of the operator, but adding `return *this;` will resolve the segfault problem.

Comment: @user5402 you are right: the code would compile.  But updating the operand would not work as one expects.  What would be the result of `(p-q)*(p+q)` if `+` `-` and `*` would overwrite  their left operand ?